# MVVM listview checkbox that selects item when checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using a checkbox in a listview in MVVM.  I am binding the 'IsChecked' attribute of a checkbox to a model property on the selected item so that I will know if a record is active or inactive.  I need to save this status to the database whenever the user checks this box, so I need the selected item to gather the details to save the change with a command.

If the user selects the record, and then checks or unchecks the checkbox, the selected item passes as a command parameter and it works as expected.  The problem I have is that when a user simply checks or unchecks the checkbox and doesn't select the item.  The command parameter is then either null, or passes the wrong selected item if a different one was selected.  How do I get the checkbox to select the item so that the correct selected item is always passed into the command parameter?

Checkbox used in listview...

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"                                         
          Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
             AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ChangeCheckedHomePlayerCmd}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=homeListBox, Path=SelectedItem}">
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: That is exactly my issue.  So, when the user DOES check or uncheck the checkbox, I need the row to be selected automatically so that when the command is called, the correct selected item is passed in as the command parameter.

Comment: @nikotromus If you want to pass the corresponding item of your `CheckBox` as a `CommandParameter`, you can just do this `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`. Or did i misunderstand  something?

Comment: @nosale - Good God.  That was it.  I spent a long, long time trying to get that to work.  Thanks you!  If you put it into the form of an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the corresponding item as `CommandParameter` you can simply do this

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

Comment: This was a fantastic solution.  I banged my head on a wall for hours trying to get this to work.